# Reading strings in python

Tags: python, string, match, python-re

I am using python to try to separate the information from strings of this type:

```
r = "(-0.04530261550379927+0j) [X0 X1 Y2 Y3]"
```

ultimately the information that I need is the number in the parenthesis and separate the letters from the numbers in the array. So in the example above, the results that I would like to get are: the number `-0.04530261550379927`, an array: `[X, X, Y, Y]` and another array: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

I have been trying with `re.match` but since this is the first time that I use this module I find it very confusing.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You could share your best attempt at solving this with well chosen sample input and the corresponding output, this could be a good starting point to help you understand what improvements your code needs. Also, some points are unclear: 1/ the sample data contains a complex number, your expected output is a float. What about the imaginary part? 2/ In the second part, would it always be exactly one letter followed by exactly one digit, and this exactly four times? Please clarify.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille For all the data that I have the imaginary part is always 0 so it is no problem. In the second part, sometimes the array might be empty, or otherwise it will always be a letter followed by exactly one number, not necessarily exactly four times, could be one, two or three as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```py
import re

r = "(-0.04530261550379927+0j) [X0 X1 Y2 Y3]"
match = re.match(r"\(([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\+\d+j\) \[((?:[XYZ]\d(?: [XYZ]\d)*)?)]", r)
number, array = match.groups()

number = float(number)
a1, a2 = [], []
for i in array.split():
    a1.append(i[0])
    a2.append(int(i[1]))

print(number, a1, a2)
```

**Explanation:**

Regex pattern `r"\(([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\+\d+j\) \[((?:[XYZ]\d(?: [XYZ]\d)*)?)]"` matches the given string:

- part `([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` matches number
- part `((?:[XYZ]\d(?: [XYZ]\d)*)?)` matches array
- there are non-capturing groups defined like `(?:<match>)`

`match.groups()` returns a list of all captured groups (2 in our case), and we unpack the list to variables `number`, `array`

Next, we split our string stored in `array` by space and iterate through items:

- first character is appended to `a1`
- second character is converted to int and appended to `a2`

---

**Output:**

```
-0.04530261550379927 ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'] [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It works well, only that I should have explained better my question: I could also have arrays of the form [] or [X0] for instance, in which case this doesn't seem to work well.

Comment: @reich98 Got it, updated the answer with a new regex pattern that matches dynamic arrays!

Comment: +1 Note that the digit `[\d]+` does not have to be between square brackets. As a small suggestion, if you repeat the last part between the square bracket with a leading space in the group you don't need the question mark and then there can be no trailing space. `\(([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\+\d+j\) \[([XYZ]\d(?: [XYZ]\d)*)]` See https://regex101.com/r/HbDlN7/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, thanks for correcting! I will update the answer. But one problem with your suggested regex is that it doesn't match empty arrays, so I will skip that part

Comment: I am sorry I missed that part. In that case you can make the whole repeating part optional. https://regex101.com/r/M7GNuZ/1

Comment: Yep, I did so and updated the answer, thank you)

Comment: ([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)  will you describe what is happening.  What is the "?" symbol doing?  Are you excluding +0j

Comment: @GoldenLion `[-+]?` matches -+ or nothing, `\d+` matches number sequence, `(?:)` is non-capturing group, so `(?:\.\d+)?` matches a floating point part of the number if exists without capturing the group, doing so we will not receive that unneeded group when we call `match.groups()`. Hope that helps, don't forget to upvote if the answer was helpful :)

Comment: What is a none capturing group

Comment: @GoldenLion read this SO post: [What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions). Hope that helps)

Comment: I am starting to use non-capturing groups. they are very helpful